# Is it possible to combine multiple OUTPUT clauses to the same sql statement?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to do the following in a single command in SQL-Server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

1. Delete Records
2. Insert Deleted Records to another table,
3. Insert ID's of the deleted records to another table for further processing to eliminate related tables

I can do 1 and 2, 
like

```
DELETE p
OUTPUT deleted.*
INTO Table2
FROM Table1 p
```

What i would like to do is like the following

```
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
(
   ID int
)
DELETE p
OUTPUT deleted.*
INTO Table2
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
INTO @tempTable
FROM Table1 p
```

Is it possible to do this in a single command?

Comment: No you can't have more than 1 output clause in a single statement. Just like you can't have multiple where clauses. And what are you expecting to find in the inserted table from a delete statement? Perhaps what you really want is a MERGE?

Comment: Just an addition to @SeanLange's comment - look into `MERGE` combined with `OUTPUT`.